# How to generate PWM with different frequencies and duty cycles?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, texas-instruments, duty-cycle

I am going to use TMS320F28027 for PWM generation. I have to generate 5 different frequencies of PWM with different duty cycles at a same time. How it could be implemented? Can I use a single PWM signal from HRPWM of that controller and using it with timers and DAC I can generate other frequencies. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you considered the usual approach of using saw-tooth waves for frequency and comparators for the duty cycle? It can be done either digitally or analogic.

Comment: While talking about saw-tooth, it's analog signal ...

Comment: Not really, a counter register with periodic overflows is akin to digital saw-tooths and can be used for PWM generation.

Comment: Got it, but how could it help my problem....

Comment: If you need 5 different frequencies, implement 5 counters with different overflow periods in your microcontroller. To vary duty cycle, compare the counter value with a varying threshold. You will only need 5 free GPIOs, no extra hardware. Is this an acceptable answer?